# Can my laptops Intel HD 4400 display UHD on an external monitor?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am the owner of a Samsung ATIV Book 9 2014 Edition (15.6” Full HD Touch / Core™ i7) (http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP940X5J-K02US)

It has a HDMI input and a Intel HD 4400 Graphics running a 1920 x 1080 on the display. I am thinking of getting a external monitor which runs 4K - will the computer/graphic card handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect PC with 4K TV](http://superuser.com/questions/827184/connect-pc-with-4k-tv), also see: [Intel HD4000 with 4k HDMI output on Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/710547/intel-hd4000-with-4k-hdmi-output-on-linux)

Comment: The 4500U only supports HDMI 1.4a not 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.audioholics.com/hdtv-formats/hdmi-2.0-specification) website:

> To put this in perspective, and illustrate why HDMI 2.0 is so important and necessary, we can take a look at current televisions on the market. The HDMI 1.4a ports on current UHD TVs from Samsung, LG, Toshiba and Sony can receive full resolution UHD or 2160p signals (3840x2160), but they can't do so at frame rates greater than 24 frames per second. While this is sufficient for movies, it's not good enough for even current 2160p television broadcasts which will use 50 or 60 fps.

If it works, it will maximum be with 24 fps since your manual does not mention HDMI2 (and manufactures are always very happy put put a "better" version as feature in their manual).

Comment: The [official HDMI spec](http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/hdmi_1_4_faq.aspx#21) says that HDMI 1.4 is able to display 4k (DCI-standard at 4096x2160) at a refresh rate of 24Hz and UHD (the display standard at 3840x2160) at 30Hz, which is higher than the 24 that you cite.

Comment: The question is specifically about if it would run on 4k, to which you say as well that the maximum is 24Hz.

Comment: Well, you are partly correct. Since almost every '4k' consumer monitor is actually UHD and not really DCI-4k, you assumed the OP was talking correctly about 4k, while that is not the case. The title of the question hints to this fact as well.